# Finding controls in placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio, user-controls

i'm using AJAX to make a user control which contains a panel that contains label and RadioButtonList or CheckBoxList according to a condition.
There is a placeholder in .aspx page where that control should be in.
I need to find List from placeholder
I tried this:

```
 public static int id = 1;
    QuestionPanelControl q1 ;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           LoadQuestionPanelControl();
       }
    }

    //Next Button
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        id++;
        if (id <= 10)
        {
            //LoadQuestionPanelControl();
            PlaceHolder p = (PlaceHolder)Page.FindControl("PlaceHolder1");
            QuestionPanelControl c1 = (QuestionPanelControl)p.FindControl("QuestionPanelControl1");
           // QuestionPanelControl c1 = (QuestionPanelControl)p.FindControl("Panel_Question");
            RadioButtonList rb = c1.ChildRadioButtonList;
            if (rb.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                //DB 
            }
            else if (rb.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                //DB
            }
            else
            {
                Lsb_Unanswered.Items.Add("Question #" + id);
            }

            LoadQuestionPanelControl();

        }
    }

public void LoadQuestionPanelControl()
    {
        Session.Add("ID",id);
        q1= new QuestionPanelControl();
        q1.ID = "QuestionPanelControl1";
        Control c = Page.LoadControl("QuestionPanelControl.ascx");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(c);

    }
```

When I use break points, I found that Controls property of p is 0.

Note: ChildRadioButtonList is a property in the QuestionPanelControl.
Any suggestions...

Comment: How and when are you adding QuestionPanelControl to the placeholder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

```
PlaceHolder p = (PlaceHolder)FindControlRecursive(Page, "PlaceHolder1");



public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control ctrl, string controlID)
{
 if (string.Compare(ctrl.ID, controlID, true) == 0)
 {
  // We found the control!
  return ctrl;
 }
 else
 {
  // Recurse through ctrl's Controls collections
  foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
  {
   Control lookFor = FindControlRecursive(child, controlID);

   if (lookFor != null)
   return lookFor;  // We found the control
  }

 // If we reach here, control was not found
 return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before already, but I didn't know how to call it. What should I write instead of Control ctrl prameter?

Comment: @noor: You should write Page or this

Comment: Do you mean that this function will be in .ascx page?

Comment: @noor: this function is static, it can be placed anywhere

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
   public void LoadQuestionPanelControl()
    {
        Session.Add("ID",id);
        Control c = Page.LoadControl("QuestionPanelControl.ascx");
        var q1= c as QuestionPanelControl;
        if(q1 != null)
        {
            q1.ID = "QuestionPanelControl1";

            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(q1);
        }

    }
```

and see if the Controls.Count for the placeholder is something other than 0.

Comment: I tried that, but it throws an exception while adding radioButtonList to the panel inside the control.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object  Exception.

Comment: Can you post the portion of the user control code where this exception occurs?

Comment: ListItem rb_Answer_True = new ListItem("True", "T");
                ListItem rb_Answer_False = new ListItem("False", "F");
                //Adding list items to RadioButtonList
                rbl_Answers.Items.Add(rb_Answer_True);  
                rbl_Answers.Items.Add(rb_Answer_False);
                //Adding RadioButtonList tp panel
                Panel_Question.Controls.Add(rbl_Answers); //Here

Comment: Sorry I can't format it, but i'm trying to add 2 listItems to RadioButtoList, then adding it to the panel.