# find and get access to PlaceHolders by ID located in aspx from codebehind

Tags: c#, webforms

This problem seems simple .. But I can't get it to work. I have multiple PlaceHolders in my aspx file:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph2"></asp:PlaceHolder>
... 
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phn"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and I'd like to get a reference to these placeHolders but my `FindControl` Method consistently returns null. Perhaps I am confusing my contexts. I try variations like:

```
private void AddStuffToPlaceHolderByID(String id){
    Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
    //Also tried Page.FindControl(id) but no luck.
    var ctrl = page.FindControl(id);
    if (ctrl != null)
        ctrl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Some Stuff"));
}
```

But `ctrl` is null.

Perhaps an alternative is to search the page class's properties for the Placeholder variable by name using `System.Reflection` but I haven't gotten too much luck out of that either and it seems to be a roundabout way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding controls in placeholder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542901/finding-controls-in-placeholder)

Comment: you need to find the control of the PlaceHolder since you are not showing how this method is being called `AddStuffToPlaceHolderByID` can you edit it the question and show all relevant code as it pertains to the `AddStuffToPlaceHolderByID` and how it's called..?